Identify this symbol?
In an arrangement of 'We go together' that my marching band plays, there is one point when the trumpets are instructed to make a wah-wah-wah-wah sound on four notes. These notes, along with the text, have the symbol +o on top of them. (I believe these were a high C, B, Bb, A.) I would like to recreate this sound in a Musescore arrangement and I am wondering what it is and if it is the right thing for my purpose.
Again, the symbol is: +o
Thanks for any help!
Gill

Are you asking how to notate wah with a mute or how to make musescore make that sound? Or are you asking us to explain the +o notation?

@ToddWilcox Aah pretty much all...

In MuseScore those symbols are on the articulation palette. They mean "muted" (+) and "open" (o) and are the standard notation for the wah-wah effect you're describing.

Thanks Aaron! You were extremely fast!

@Gill P You can add both articulations to the same note but they'll display stacked vertically by default.   You can drag the 'o' into position after the '+' though.    MuseScore has an open trumpet sound and a  muted trumpet sound.  It doesn't offer a 'wah' sound.    (Another way of notating this is to write 'wah' over each note.)
